# How to make Safari warn me with a pop-up window before closing a tab?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, safari-extensions, chrome-extensions

Whether it is Chrome, Firefox or Safari, I always encounter this problem. I stream this video and let it loads for like 30 minutes so I can watch. Meanwhile, I navigate through my 10 other tabs. At some point I want to check how's the progress on the streaming video download. But all of a sudden, I accidentally click on the little cross that's hidden to close on the video tab and al the download is lost!

I'm using Safari, so I need a fix for this browser, maybe Chrome too. I noticed that if I'm on Safari and the page is a form and I accidentally close the tab, it warns me if I'm sure I want to close the tab. I wish it could do the same for any tab.

Does anyone know a trick or extension that would help?

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, you could use the Pinned Tab feature.

> Pinned Tabs allow you to always keep your favorite web apps like
>   Facebook, Gmail and Twitter open and just a click away. Pinned Tabs
>   are small, can't be closed accidentally and open automatically when
>   you start Firefox.

To create a pinned tab just "<kbd>ctrl</kbd> click" on it and select pin tab. Now you can not accidentally close it.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open

In Safari you would use the Top Sites feature displaying thumbnail images of the web sites you visit most often. There you can Pin a Tab.

[image: pin top]

Comment: I like this Firefox extension Buscar웃SD because I thought about the problem of having to constantly click on the are-you-sure-you-want-to-close-this-tab button when I would only need it for some sensitive tabs such as loaded video I wouldn't want to reload again.
I didn't get your last sentence though for Safari and how it would help to not accidentally close a tab.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using your mouse you can use the keyboard to cycle through the tabs. The keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will go forward through your ten tabs and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will go backward. At no time will these key commands close a tab by mistake.

Should you want to close a tab however you can achieve this with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Once you've finished using your browser you can close it with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Edit: Further to my answer in the latest version of Safari you have the ability to pin tabs. Once a tab is pinned the only way to close it is to right click it with the mouse and select "close tab" Even the Command + W keyboard combination won't close it.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, that's an idea. However I think this is one particular case where using shortcut here would be slightly slower than using the mouse. I use tons of shortcut including the 2 last ones you mentioned to save time instead of moving the mouse but I personally prefer to use the mouse in this very specific case. But you're right, with this method no risk to close a task by accident.